# Why am I getting this error: Class "Google_Service_Calendar" not found?

Tags: php

Here is my code: this is just a sample Quickstart.php from Google Developers:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)));
```

the last line is throwing this error: "class Google_Service_Calendar" not found. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
$ composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
$ php -r 'require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; var_dump(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);'
string(49) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
```

Given this, your autoload is probably messed up.  Try `composer dump-autoload`.

Failing that, perhaps you're depending upon an older version of the API client that doesn't have that class.  Try:

```
$ composer show -i | grep apiclient
google/apiclient    v2.0.0-RC4 Client library for Google APIs
```

Comment: thank you so much, I haven't even begun working on my project, this was just supposed to get me acclimated to working with the calendar. I will try. thanks again

Comment: y/w and good luck!  Please do let us know what ultimately solves the problem. :)

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel '/vendor/autoload.php' is a file generated by Composer a dependency management program for PHP. If you want to use the API library you either need to run the require command like bishop said or add it to an existing composer.json file and run `composer update`. It will then install all the necessary dependencys.Also take a look at [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) it might help.